# Migration to Debian Stretch ask about 'Wheezy'

Tags: debian, migration

There was Debian Jessie on server and I tried to migrate it to **Debian Stretch**.
I want to upgrade our server to actual version of Debian.

The command `sudo apt-get update` give me errors:

```
Err http://ftp.us.debian.org wheezy/main Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.233.100 80]
Err http://ftp.us.debian.org wheezy/contrib Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.233.100 80]
Err http://ftp.us.debian.org wheezy/non-free Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.233.100 80]
Err http://ftp.us.debian.org wheezy/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.233.100 80]
Err http://ftp.us.debian.org wheezy/contrib amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.233.100 80]
Err http://ftp.us.debian.org wheezy/non-free amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.233.100 80]
```

After running `apt install apt -t stretch` there are different errors but still about 'Wheezy':

```
W: The repository 'http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian wheezy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://downloads.opsview.com/opsview-core/latest/apt wheezy InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: 3814C24CF407EC2F9EB07631327C70CD0FC6984B
W: Failed to fetch http://downloads.opsview.com/opsview-core/latest/apt/dists/wheezy/InRelease  The following signatures were invalid: 3814C24CF407EC2F9EB07631327C70CD0FC6984B
E: Failed to fetch http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/dists/wheezy/contrib/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 208.80.154.15 80]
```

The command `sudo apt-get upgrade` executed ok.

The command `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` also return error about "wheezy":

```
Err http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main sysvinit amd64 2.88dsf-41+deb7u1
  404  Not Found [IP: 208.80.154.15 80]
```

The file `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
#deb http://ftp.nl.debian.org/debian stretch main

deb http://ftp.nl.debian.org/debian stretch main non-free contrib
deb-src http://ftp.nl.debian.org/debian stretch main non-free contrib

deb http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free

# stretch-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.nl.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.nl.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main contrib non-free

deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial main
```

Probably I should change something in config files, but I don't know what and where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There’s probably another configuration file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` referencing Wheezy. You should remove those entries too.

The errors are harmless, but I understand why you want to get rid of them!